# How to create password protected zip/7zip file using apache.compress

Tags: java, android, zip, apache-commons, 7zip

In my `Android` project, I'm using below dependency in my `build.gradle` file to support extraction/compression of archive files

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.21'
```

I want to know how can I create password protected zip/7zip file using apache.compress.
I'm referring this documentation [Apache Compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/index.html)

I'm able to create zip/7zip archives but not able to set password to those archives.

I tried but couldn't find anywhere.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You just can't. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/limitations.html For 7z, "Encryption, solid compression and header compression are only supported when reading archives" while for zip, "no support for encryption", use http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/compression_snippets.html#create-encrypted instead

Comment: Yes the limitation doc says so, but I'm able to extract an encrypted zip file using apache so thought this documentation is not updated it seems.

Comment: The historical issue is that passwords of zips are not very secure. Better to encrypt a mail or such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache compress library does not support creating archives(zip/7zip files)